# Small explanation about divide action JAVA

Tags: java, divide

I have a small question about divide action in Java.

I have a `contain()` function that moves across all of my array and calls an `equals()` that I made.

Now I made a new `equals1()` function and the time test is much better.

When I use the `equals()` function, my time test takes 3000 ms, and when I use the `equals1()` function, my time test takes 500 ms.
It's a difference of several hundred percent.
I hope someone can tell me this.

Thanks

```
public boolean equals1(Fraction f) {
    return this.denominator == f.denominator
            && this.numerator == f.numerator;
}

public boolean equals(Fraction f) {
    if ((double) this.numerator / (double) this.denominator
            == (double) f.numerator / (double) f.denominator) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of the number of operations being performed.

In the `equals` method you are doing a lot:

1. Cast variable to double × 4
2. Division × 2
3. == comparison × 1
4. Evaluate if statement × 1
5. return × 1

In the `equals1` method, you do a lot less:

1. == comparison × 2
2. && comparison × 1
3. return × 1